# AngularJS: Matrix determinant. Issue with number comparison?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, angularjs, matrix

I found a javascript determinant algorithm from a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588100/recursive-function-for-matrix-determinant-calculator). My application seems to work fine, as long as the matrix is a 2x2. Anything beyond that and the algorithm doesn't calculate the determinant correctly.

I tried to debug line by line and it seems, a certain set of 'if' conditions are not being met.

This is my entire script. You can scroll down to the bottom, find calcRec function and look for the comment that says "//Neither of the below 2 conditions are fulfilled.". This is the part where I fail to understand the problem with. You can find the plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5l1t80rduqG7sQIpSHeF?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


$scope.matrix = [[{"val":0},{"val":1}],[{"val":3},{"val":4}]]

var rowLength = $scope.matrix[0].length;
var colLength = $scope.matrix.length;


var addRow = function()
{
this.rowLength = $scope.matrix[0].length;
this.colLength = $scope.matrix.length;

var array = [];
for(var i=0;i<this.rowLength;i++)
{
  array.push({"val":0});
}
$scope.matrix.push(array);

};

 var addCol = function()
{
this.rowLength =   $scope.matrix[0].length;
this.colLength = $scope.matrix.length;
for(var i=0;i<this.colLength;i++)
{
  $scope.matrix[i].push({"val":0});
}
};

var removeRow = function()
{
this.rowLength =   $scope.matrix[0].length;
this.colLength = $scope.matrix.length;
$scope.matrix.splice(this.colLength-1,1);
};

var removeCol = function()
{
this.rowLength =   $scope.matrix[0].length;
this.colLength = $scope.matrix.length;
for(var i=0;i<this.colLength;i++)
{
  $scope.matrix[i].splice(this.rowLength-1,1);
}
};

$scope.increaseSize = function()
{
addCol();
addRow();
$scope.updateDeterminant();
};

$scope.decreaseSize = function()
{
removeCol();
removeRow();
$scope.updateDeterminant();
};

$scope.updateDeterminant = function()
{
var tempMatrix = $scope.matrix;
var k = this.rowLength;
$scope.determinantValue = calcRec(tempMatrix);
//To be continued.
};



var calcRec = function(A) 
{
    var s;
    var k = this.rowLength;
    var det = 0;
    if (A.length == 1) 
    { //bottom case of the recursive function 
        return A[0][0].val;
    }
    if (A.length == 2) 
    {       
        det =  A[0][0].val * A[1][1].val - A[1][0].val * A [0][1].val;
        return det;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < this.k; i++) 
    {

        //creates smaller matrix- values not in same row, column
        var smaller = new Array(A.length - 1);
        for (var h = 0; h < smaller.length; h++) 
        {
            smaller[h] = new Array(A.length - 1);

        }

        for (var a = 1; a < A.length; a++) 
        {

            for (var b = 0; b < A.length; b++) 
            {
                //Neither of the below 2 conditions are fulfilled.

                if (b<i) 
                {

                    smaller[a-1][b].val = A[a][b].val;

                } 
                else if(b>i) 
                {
                    smaller[a - 1][b - 1].val = A[a][b].val;

                }

            }

        }
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            s = 1;

        } else {
            s = -1;

        }
        det += s * A[0][i].val * (calcRec(smaller));

    }
    return (calcRec(A));
}

});
```

My HTML code is here, not that you'll need it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<span ng-repeat="rows in matrix track by $index"><br>
  <span ng-repeat="element in rows track by $index">
    <textarea ng-change="updateDeterminant()" ng-model="matrix[$parent.$index]  [$index].val" rows="1" cols="1"></textarea>
  </span>
</span><br>


<button ng-click="increaseSize()">Increase Size</button><br>
<button ng-click="decreaseSize()">Decrease Size</button>
Determinant is {{determinantValue}}


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. There was a problem with the way I created the smaller matrix.

Initial code

```
var smaller = new Array(A.length - 1);
for (var h = 0; h < smaller.length; h++) 
{
    smaller[h] = new Array(A.length - 1);

}
```

Corrected code

```
var smaller = [];
for(var newvar=0;newvar<A.length-1;newvar++)
{

    var array = []

    for(var m=0;m<A.length-1;m++)
    {
      array.push({"val":0});
    }
    smaller.push(array);

}
```

Turns out, you need to be careful when you're dealing with arrays in javascript. Here's my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5l1t80rduqG7sQIpSHeF?p=preview). It now works for all nxn matrices.

Answer (score 0):

At the line 98, you initialize an array of undefined

```
smaller[h] = new Array(A.length - 1);
```

for obvious reason

```
smaller[a-1][b].val
```

throws an error, which says "TypeError: Cannot set property 'val' of undefined"

Comment: Could you elaborate? So are you saying, index bounds are maxed?

Comment: Um, no this has nothing to do with index bounds, since the two dimensional array of the required size does exist, the problem is that it stores `undefined` as value, not an object that has a `val` property

Comment: Will creating a new class (say mArray) with an attribute "val" instead, solve it?